# How to provide core points in DBSCAN?

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means, dbscan

In [sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)
 , is there a way to explicitly indicate the core points? I have prior knowledge of these core points which are actually centroids generated from K-means. The reason I want to use DBSCAN is I also want a separate cluster for the noise which is not achievable as far as I know with K-means.

Comment: The DBSCAN.fit() method computes the core points here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/6eff1757ec3698f7cc0b3cc1ed0aefd241529f8c/sklearn/cluster/_dbscan.py#L433 Maybe you could do this by subclassing DBSCAN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the centroids in DBSCAN sklearn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215910/how-to-get-the-centroids-in-dbscan-sklearn)